# about Rijndael-256 decrypt

Tags: encryption, rijndael

I'm trying to decrypt the game strings my friend gave me the key and IV in bytes and I don't know how to use it because online decryption sites usually put it in Hex and I have no experience with programming. submit. Someone help me please?

```
byte[] key = { 72, 84, 100, 107, 81, 84, 78, 109, 84, 77, 68, 49, 78, 84, 77, 52, 68, 78, 77, 48, 81, 78, 73, 104, 78, 84, 69, 101, 78, 119, 65, 51 };
byte[] iv = { 235, 38, 114, 124, 56, 159, 107, 243, 233, 120, 157, 188, 169, 142, 32, 105 };
```

Here is key and iv if you need it
encryption is `Rijndael-256`

For example
"e7c6ae7b9022cc2e9ee25b4b73ae8125" will be translated as "HeroSkin"

Thanks for reading this topic

I have tried websites that convert bytes to Hex but it doesn't work. Please show me which app or website can convert it

Comment: _"gave me the key and IV in bytes"_ you mean _decimal_. You will need to convert those decimal values to a hexadecimal string. Cyberchef is a good place to play with this kind of stuff [Convert decimal to hex](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Decimal('Comma',false)To_Hex('Space',0)&input=NzIsIDg0LCAxMDAsIDEwNywgODEsIDg0LCA3OCwgMTA5LCA4NCwgNzcsIDY4LCA0OSwgNzgsIDg0LCA3NywgNTIsIDY4LCA3OCwgNzcsIDQ4LCA4MSwgNzgsIDczLCAxMDQsIDc4LCA4NCwgNjksIDEwMSwgNzgsIDExOSwgNjUsIDUxCg)